# Execution of the new AsyncTask instance changes TextView visibility

Tags: android, android-asynctask, textview, android-alertdialog

I am having a problem with my app project and as you can see in code I have an asynctask which should check the internet connection and load necessary data from the cloud. If the connection fails, I have an alertdialog which will be shown to deliver an error message. This alertdialog has retry button to repeat the whole procedure by executing the new instance of the async task. I also have a TextView (txtRetry), which does the same. This TextView is invisible and it should stay like that as long as the user doesn't close the alertdialog. The problem is when the user clicks on the retry button in the alertdialog it starts new asynctask and it somehow makes my TextView also visible, but it should not. Do you have any idea, what could cause this problem...?

This ist the activity

```
public class InitActivity extends Activity {

private Context ctx;

    /* this textview should be invisible after
    the user clicks on the "retry" button in the alertdialog */
TextView txtRetry; 

private AlertDialog alertDialog;
private AlertDialog.Builder builder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_init);

    ctx = this;
    txtRetry = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnRetry);
    txtRetry.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            txtRetry.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            new MyAsyncTask().execute((Void[]) null);
        }
    });

    Handler handler = new Handler();

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask();
            task.setTxtRetry(txtRetry);
            task.execute((Void[]) null);
        }

    }, 1000);

    this.initializeAlertDialog();
}

private void initializeAlertDialog() {
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.ad_title);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.ad_msg);

            /* this is the retry button in the alertdialog */
    builder.setNeutralButton(R.string.btnRetry,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            alertDialog.cancel();
            alertDialog.dismiss();
            MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask();
            task.setTxtRetry(txtRetry);
            task.execute((Void[]) null);

        }
    });

    builder.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
            txtRetry.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog pd;
    String title = getResources().getString(R.string.title_pd_connecting_to_the_server);
    String msg = getResources().getString(R.string.msg_pd_connecting_to_the_server);
    boolean success = false;        
    private TextView txtRet;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
        pd.setTitle(title);
        pd.setMessage(msg);
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                    // connection to the server is simulated here...
        //TODO: Connect on the server...
        //TODO: get players count...

        try {
            //txtRet.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            success = false;
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        pd.dismiss();
        pd.cancel();

        if(success) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(InitActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("players", 4);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }

    public void setTxtRetry(TextView txtRetry) {
        txtRet = txtRetry;
    }

}
}
```

As you can see, I have also tried to set the TextView in the AsyncTask class and work with it there but it didn't help...

This is activity_init layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:textSize="90sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/logo"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/logo"
    android:text="@string/tm"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<!-- this is the text view -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtRetry"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dip"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="@string/btnRetry"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling cancel() in your onClick which in turn calls the Cancel listener and shows the TextView. Remove it and you should be good to go.

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        alertDialog.cancel();
        alertDialog.dismiss();
        MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask();
        task.setTxtRetry(txtRetry);
        task.execute((Void[]) null);
}
```

Comment: Perfect, it works! Thank you wery much, I should have asked hours ago :)

Answer (score 0):

That's happens because you can't change **UI** views **in background thread**.

If you want to change your **TextView** visibility state use a `publishProgress`method and set Visibility in `onProgressChanged` method.

```
For example :

void doInBackground(...)
{
 // myProgress is changed...
 publishProgress(myProgress);
}

void onProgressChanged(Integer value)
{
    if(value.intValue() == 0)
        myTextView.setVisibility(View.Invisible);
}
```

If you need to change visibility in secondary launch do that **in UI thread**.

Answer (score 0):

You have an OnCancelListener() for your dialog box. In that you have it change the visibility of your textview to visible. Then on your only button in that box you call for it to cancel which triggers that OnCancelListener();

If you remove the

alertDialog.cancel();

and leave

alertDialog.dismiss();

your dialog box shoule dismiss but not call the OnCancelListener().